# Why can't I use yytext inside yyerror (Yacc)

Tags: yacc

Im having some trouble with my analizer. I.m trying to use yytext inside my yyerror but it shows me this error, can you help me?

[image: error]

[image: yyerror declaration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `yytext` in your parser because it is defined by the lexer.

Indeed, you normally shouldn't use `yytext` in your parser because its value is not meaningful to the parse. Your attempt to use it to provide context in error messages is just about the only reasonable use, and even then there is a certain ambiguity because you can't tell whether the erroneous token is the one currently in `yytext` or the previous token, which was overwritten when the parser obtained its lookahead token.

In any case, if you want to refer to `yytext` inside your parser, you'll need to declare it, which will normally require putting

```
extern char* yytext;
```

into your bison grammar file. Since the only place you can reasonably use `yytext` is `yyerror`, you might change the definition of that function to:

```
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
  extern char* yytext;
  fprintf(stderr, "%s at line %d near '%s'\n", msg, nLineas, yytext);
}
```

Note that you can get flex to track line numbers automatically, so you don't need to track your own `nLineas` variable. Just add

```
%option yylineno
```

at the top of your flex file, and the global variable `yylineno` will automatically be maintained during lexical analysis. If you want to use `yylineno` in your parser, you'll need to add an an `extern` declaration for it as well:

```
extern int yylineno;
```

Again, using `yylineno` in the parser may be imprecise because it might refer to the line number of the token following the error, which might be on a different line from the error (and might even be separated from the error by many lines of comments).

---

As an alternative to using external declarations of `yytext` and `yylineno`, you are free to put the implementation of `yyerror` inside the scanner definition instead of the grammar definition. Your grammar file should already have a forward declaration of `yyerror`, so it doesn't matter which file it's placed in. If you put it into the scanner file, global scanner variables will already be declared.